# add hyperlink to an image(background image)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit lost as to how to add a hyperlink to an image(background image) that is being called into the page with this HTML below:

```
<div style="background-color: #fff; background: #fff url(/affiliate/uploads/images/subs_bg_4e1a7912cf9a79.22853644.jpg) no-repeat right top" class="bigshadow" id="wrapper"></div>
```

**i need to add a hyper-link into the background image.**

Comment: Not possible. Consider adding an `onclick`  even to the `div` itself

Comment: Yes Pekka's suggestion is the way to go. Add an onclick listener to the div. When the image is clicked, the event will bubble up to the div.

Comment: Is there any reason that the `<div>` can't just be an anchor (`<a>`) tag itself with a href, or that the background-image could just be an `<img>` tag wrapped in an `<a>`?

Answer (score 2):

$("#wrapper").click(function(){here goes redirect})
Or u just need background-image: ??

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#wrapper').live('click',function(){
   location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com";
});
```

i'd use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) since your question implies that the div is added to the page dynamically.

---

if you really want to insert hyperlink (a element) you could do:

```
$('#wrapper').append($('<a/>',{'html':'<br/>','href':'http://www.yoursite.com'}).css({'display':'block','height':'100%','width':'100%'}));
```

you maybe want to run all that on the class instead of id so it works for multiple elements

Answer (score 0):

Put a link inside your div with `display:block` like this: (this trick works even in ie6,7,8)

html:

```
<div style="background-color: #fff; background: #fff url(img.jpg) no-repeat right top" class="bigshadow" id="wrapper">
    <a title="click here" href="http://mysite.com"><span>MySite.com</span></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper a {
    display: block;
    height: 101px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y6YMe/1/).

Comment: Why bother adding img.jpg as a background-image to both the anchor and the `<div>`? Why not just create an anchor and put an `<img>` inside it, or wrap the `<div>` with the `<a>`?

Comment: You're right, background-image can be only on the div (edited my answer)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. chris, i cannot use click function as wrapper div is the main div in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it *has* to be a `<div>` with a background-image... that just means that you'll be in agony city trying to force the browser to do something because of improper use of markup.

It's unclear from your question as to whether you have control over the source of that `<div>`.

If you *do* have control over what creates that `<div>`, I would recommend changing it to an `<img src="pathtotheimage.jpg"/>` and wrapping it in an anchor (`<a>`) tag:

If you have *no control* over the creation of the `<div>`, then I suggest extracting the image URL out of it and employing proper semantic markup anyway.

In either case, here's the markup you should be aiming for:

```
<a href="#" id="wrapper" class="bigshadow">
     <img src="/affiliate/uploads/images/subs_bg_4e1a7912cf9a79.22853644.jpg" />
</a>
```

Doing it this way, you require *no additional CSS* to achieve what you want -- a clickable image.

If you need to extract the image URL out of the response, then do this:

```
function extractImageUrl(html) {
    return $(html).css('background-image').replace(/url\(\"(.*?)\"\)/, "$1");
}
```